# laravel scout search with multiple model

Tags: php, laravel, search, laravel-scout

I used this old code, and start refactor it with use of `laravel/scout`.
This code is a simply search function thet search in posts and pages too, and show result mixed paginate.

Old code:

```
public function search($term) {
   $post = Post::where('title', 'LIKE', $term);
   $page = Page::where('content', 'LIKE', $term);
   $result = $page->union($post)->orderBy('created_at')->paginate();
   return $result;
}
```

New Code not working:

```
public function search($term) {
   $post = Post::search($term);
   $page = Page::search($term);
   $result = $page->union($post)->orderBy('created_at')->paginate(); 
   return $result;
}
```

get error: `Method Laravel\Scout\Builder::union does not exist.`

What is the best syntax for this problem?

Comment: Scout's search functionality is implemented in engines and is specific to how the engines manage data. Scout's `Builder` doesn't use `QueryBuiler` directly due to the same reason. Implementing `union` to work across all engines may not be possible or atleast not trivial to do. If sure to use a particular engine (say database engine) then you may try to implement your custom version with `union` functionality taking currently used engine as starting point to extend it. And then extend the `Scout\Builder` with a `macro` to use the extended functionality.

Comment: Just a thought - wouldn't it be easier to merge the paginated results for individual models and send merged results to frontend?

Answer (score 3):

Since `Scout\Builder` doesn't support `union`. And it would be non trivial to implement `union` functionality for all possible search engines supported by Scout.

However, `Scout\Builder` provides a **query()** function to customise the eloquent results query.

This provides kind of an escape hatch, where by scout can be leveraged on one model (out of the two)

```php
public function search($term)
{
    $postQuery = Post::query()
        ->where('some_column', 'like', $term . "%");
    $results = Page::search($term)
        ->query(
            fn($query) => $query->union($postQuery)
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        )
        ->paginate();
}
```

[Laravel Scout - Customizing the Eloquent Results Query](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scout#customizing-the-eloquent-results-query)

###### For Algolia Engine

If using Algolia as search engine, there's [Algolia Scout Extended](https://www.algolia.com/doc/framework-integration/laravel/getting-started/introduction-to-scout-extended/?client=php) which supports search with multiple models.

###### For other Engines

Another approach to search multiple models with Scout and get paginated results would be:

- Get search results for individual models using Scout (using `Model::search('query')->get();`)
- Concat the resulting collections
- Paginate the collection

Define a macro for `Illuminate\Support\Collection` in the `boot` method of a Service Provider (for eg in `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider`)

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Collection::macro('paginate', function ($perPage, $total = null, $page = null, $pageName = 'page') {
            $page = $page ?: LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage($pageName);

            return new LengthAwarePaginator(
                $total ? $this : $this->forPage($page, $perPage)->values(),
                $total ?: $this->count(),
                $perPage,
                $page,
                [
                    'path'     => LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPath(),
                    'pageName' => $pageName,
                ]
            );
        });
    }
}
```

Then in the controller

```php
public function search($term) {
   $post = Post::where('title', 'LIKE', $term)->get();
   $page = Page::where('content', 'LIKE', $term)->get();
   $result = $page->concat($post)->sortBy('created_at')->paginate(5);
   return $result;
}
```